# Cannot filter a SharePoint 2013 Task List after March 2015 Update

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Not sure if anyone else has noticed this, but for some reason after I installed the SharePoint 2013 March 2015 CU I am unable to filter Task Lists using a view. (April 2015 does not work either) Even the default Completed view does not work. All items are begin displayed. I have tested this on four different servers now. There is a checkbox in the web part properties that allows for server rendering which I am currently using as a work around but I would like to get the client side rendering to work again as it had before the CU.

Comment: Hello!
I have encountered the same problem and it seems too be related to the CU. I have tested different approaches, but with no results.
I have submitted a ticket to Microsoft and will hopefully have an answer soon.

Comment: I have also submitted a ticket with MS Support. They are currently doing some investigation. I will post their response as soon as I get it. The workaround listed below is not ideal as it reverts the view back to SP 2010 functionality which does not support sub tasks

Comment: Having the same issue.   Note that it only seems to be effecting Task Lists.  All my other lists work fine.

Comment: Is there an official way to communicate this bug to Microsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just confirmed that the May 2015 Cumulative update contains a fix for the issue listed above http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47213

Please note that the CU does take quite a while to install and requires the server to be rebooted

Comment: We just upgrade our enviornments to Apr 2015 CU.  do we have any workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Was contacted by Microsoft yesterday.

**Short summary:**

At the moment there are no solutions for this problem, but they are working on a new smaller CU update that will include a fix. They could not give me a timeframe for when this update will be published, but they told me "very soon".

**There are two quick/temporary fixes:**

**1.**  On the page go to Settings -> Edit Page -> Select the List Web Part and the option Edit Web part -> Miscellaneous -> Server Render (Checkbox).

**2.**  Go to the list -> select and edit view -> expand "Style" -> Chose any style besides "Default". The style "Shaded" is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Note that both of these solutions we lose the ability to Search the list, and easily change the view, which both are heavily used at our place.  Hope they can fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

After applying the March 2015 CU (and possibly MS15-022), it is no longer possible to Filter a View based on criteria in the Task list (e.g. Task Status). This appears to only impact new Task Lists created post-patch. One workaround is to place the Task list on a Page. Edit the Web Part and check "Server Render" under Miscellaneous. This does not appear to be a Lists.asmx Web Service issue as the filtered view correctly filters in 3rd party tools.

http://nauplius57.rssing.com/chan-11167629/latest.php

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into the issue above but it happened on a custom list (not issue derived) with March 2016 CU applied. This is the first instance I found so far. I corrected it by doing the following:

1. Edit the listview page.
2. Edit the listview web part
3. In the Miscellaneous section, click Server Render
4. Save web part settings and page.
5. Repeat 1-4 except uncheck Server Render.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, but on a SharePoint 2013 BCS External List. Filtering with "yes" on a Yes/No column seems to do nothing, return all rows as is. Also when I choose to filter by a date on DateTime columns, no rows were returned.

Changing the view style to "Shaded" and enabling "Server Render" solved the above issues.

Downside to this solution is that you loose the ability to use JS Link / CSR.